# WooCommerce char display error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, localization, special-characters

I'm stuck on a wordpress plugin which wont display the letter Ü

Here's the code inside the `/checkoutbuilder/index.php`

```
wp_localize_script( 'checkout-builder', 'object_name_checkout', array("text_prev"=>"zurück","text_next"=>"Weiter") );
```

But instead of `zurück` the button shows `zur?ck`.

I hope someone can lead me to a solution.

Comment: try to change the charset of you browser to find one charset which works

Answer (score 0):

Try unescaping to see if you get a different result.

```
wp_localize_script( 'checkout-builder', 'object_name_checkout', unescape((array("text_prev"=>"zurück","text_next"=>"Weiter")) );
```

Comment: Definitely not good. Revert. Make sure the encoding inside wp-config.php is define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); It's an encoding problem.